# How to add a voice using Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I've been reading the [Web Speech Api documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) and I've done some examples but i would like to change the voice but not for a standard system voice (voices getting by executing SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()).
The [SpeechSynthesisVoice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisVoice) object has the voiceURI property that indicates the speech synthesis service.
I think that i need to make a SpeechSynthesisVoice object indicating my speech synthesis service but i don't know how to make one or where can I found one. 
   The question is: Is there any open source platform that provides that or I must use the voices provided by the browser (voices getting by executing SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()) ?

Comment: How you did that finally?

Answer (score 2):

In the current draft specification, the `SpeechSynthesisVoice` object has only read-only fields. Each combination of browser and operating system has different type of speech synthesis mechanisms and each one of them has different types of voices.

If you want to control the voice you need to use external server. I've used [CloudASR](https://www.cloudasr.com/) and it works perfectly for both speech synthesis and speech recognition. It's also very easy to play with because all you need to do it to install a Docker container and simply run it.

Comment: I'll try it, but, ideally, i would like to know a way to add voices on browser (or even on my operative system) but the idea is: when i execute SpeechSynthesis.getVoices() get the voice that i've added (I don't know how to add a voice) on my system (Browser, web page or operative system).

Comment: I see that CloudASR is only for speech recognition, not for text-to-speech.
Updating my question, the new version Mozilla Firefox (44.0) has the Web Speech API, it has more robotic voices than Google Chrome. Now I'm trying [festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) using some voices generated using [festvox] (http://festvox.org/download.html) and using the test2wave tool 'll generate the .mp3 or .wav. Then I'll return the audio to the view.
The main idea is to add voices (generated by festvox) on the browser or (serve them in a rest service) and use only  Web Speech API.